# loading/registering a DLL before running the program

Tags: c++, c

I have a DLL that exists in a certain location. I create another application that depends on this DLL. How do I reference the DLL at runtime? If I keep the DLL in the same directory as the exe, it works. However, that is not in my case. I tried to use regsvr32.exe to load and register the library in registry. But when I do that and then run the exe, it doesn't pick it up.

If you could give me some options, that would be great. And also why regsvr32.exe is not working in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Regsvr32.exe only works on a specific kind of DLL, an in-process COM server.  If it complains that it can't find the DllRegisterServer entrypoint then it is not such a DLL.

Sharing DLLs was something that made sense in the previous century, back when a machine had 16 megabytes of RAM and the entire operating system was as large as the "Gone Fishing" wallpaper bitmap of Windows 7.  These days you go out of your way to *prevent* sharing DLLs.  So you'll escape the dreaded [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).  Particularly a problem with COM servers.

But you can, you'll have to [add the directory](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) to the PATH environment variable.  An application can do it too by calling SetDllDirectory().  Assuming it knows where the DLL is located, that's not typical.

Best way is just not do this.  Just copy the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for locating DLLs are found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.80).aspx

Note that you can add the relevant directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

If you have a specific location that your file can always be found (or configurable from your application), you can specify a path in your call to `LoadLibrary`.